# How to validate a encrypted field

Tags: apex, developer

on the best practice section of this documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm

it says:
You can still validate the values of encrypted fields using validation rules or Apex. Both work regardless of whether the user has the “View Encrypted Data” permission.

But if I dont have the permission and I try to do something like

```
Contact con = [SELECT Id, My_Encrypted__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = '0030I00001WoR9E'];
if (con.My_Encrypted__c == '456798') {
    System.debug('yess');
} else {
    System.debug('noooo');    
}
```

The debug log will show me noooo. So my question is how can I validate the field, or I am misunderstanding that sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate values in an Apex trigger by checking the values in Trigger.new or Trigger.old, and you can validate values in [Validation Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_validation_rules.htm&type=5). If you query records without having the "View Encrypted Data" permission, the values will still be masked.